# Trying to add votes using many-to-many relationship

Tags: java, annotations, many-to-many, playframework-2.1

I'm having some troubles implementing a vote function to my play-framework web application.

Currently i  have defined these variables in class that should have a "score" of votes.

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
public List<User> upVotes = new ArrayList<User>();

@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
public List<User> downVotes = new ArrayList<User>();
```

In the same class i also implemented some methods so a user can toggle their vote.

```
public void toggleUpVote(User user){
    if(user == null){
        // Do nothing
        Logger.debug("Vote: User is null!");
    }
    else if(upVotes.contains(user)){
        Logger.debug("Vote: removed upvote!");
        upVotes.remove(user);
        this.saveManyToManyAssociations("upVotes");
    } else {
        if(downVotes.contains(user)){
            Logger.debug("Vote: removed old downvote!");
            downVotes.remove(user);
            this.saveManyToManyAssociations("downVotes");
        }
        Logger.debug("Vote: Added upvote!");
        upVotes.add(user);
        this.saveManyToManyAssociations("upVotes");
    }
    Logger.debug("Uservotestatus: " + getVoteStatus(user));
    this.save();
}

public void toggleDownVote(User user){
    if(user == null){
        // Do nothing
        Logger.debug("Vote: User is null!");
    } else if(downVotes.contains(user)){
        Logger.debug("Vote: removed downvote!");
        downVotes.remove(user);
        this.saveManyToManyAssociations("downVotes");
    } else {
        if(upVotes.contains(user)){
            Logger.debug("Vote: removed old upvote!");
            upVotes.remove(user);
            this.saveManyToManyAssociations("upVotes");
        }
        Logger.debug("Vote: Added downvote!");
        downVotes.add(user);
        this.saveManyToManyAssociations("downVotes");
    }
    Logger.debug("Uservotestatus: " + getVoteStatus(user));
    this.save();
}

public int getVoteStatus(User user){
    if(upVotes.contains(user)){
        return 1;
    } else if (downVotes.contains(user)) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

public int getScore(){
    Logger.debug("upVotes: " + upVotes.size());
    Logger.debug("downVotes: " + downVotes.size());

    Logger.debug("upvotes: "+ upVotes + "downvotes:" + downVotes);
    return (upVotes.size() - downVotes.size());
```

It seems like whenever i add a user to the upVotes list it also gets added to the downVotes list. The voting functionality seems to work just fine, i also tested the model to make sure all works fine. (Tests do work fine and doesn't get the issue) I sneak peaked in to the sql file where the tables are created and can only find this ManyToMany relationship:

```
create table note_user (
  note_id                        bigint not null,
  user_id                        varchar(255) not null,
  constraint pk_note_user primary key (note_id, user_id))
;
```

Why isn't two tables created? Do i have to name the many-to-many relationship in some way?

I've tried searched for ways to name the table by annotations but haven't found any solution.

Comment: i think you have to map the tables.

Comment: Would that change the number of tables created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by using jointable annotation.

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
@JoinTable(name="up_votes")
public List<User> upVotes = new ArrayList<User>();

@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
@JoinTable(name="down_votes")
public List<User> downVotes = new ArrayList<User>();
```

The result in the database is as follows:

```
create table up_votes (
  note_id                        bigint not null,
  user_id                        varchar(255) not null,
  constraint pk_up_votes primary key (note_id, user_id))
;

create table down_votes (
  note_id                        bigint not null,
  user_id                        varchar(255) not null,
  constraint pk_down_votes primary key (note_id, user_id))
;
```